# Multiple websites inside Docker nginx container - PHP container works only with one

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have 3 Docker containers(nginx, php and mysql) bundled together via docker-compose.

In `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` I have .conf files for 2 websites.

```
magento2.loc  > magento2.conf
pma.loc       > pma.conf
```

On the host(Ubuntu) I modified `/etc/hosts` accordingly.

```
127.0.0.1  > magent2.loc
127.0.0.1  > pma.loc
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
    nginx:
        (...)
        links:
            - php
        (...)
    php:
       (...)
```

After running `docker-compose up`, server log in console shows:

- response from php and nginx for magento2.loc < correct
- but only response from nginx(no php) from pma.loc < incorrect

How do I make pma.loc work with PHP? Do I need multiple PHP containers for that?

Comment: I've made a habit of creating separate containers for each web site. Then you have to make sure your configs are correct in order to be able to deliver both (or more) websites.

Comment: @JayBlanchard do you mean separate php containers or all? I need a single mysql container that can be accessed by phpMyAdmin and an app. Would it work with 2 x php, 2 x nginx, 1 x shared mysql?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is an app, not a database. I put the database(MySQL) in a container and then link my web containers to the MySQL container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you're trying to achieve is to first, place your database in its own container. Then, for each website create a container having the necessary components to run the website as shown below:

[image: Websites w/ Shared Database]

You would establish a link between each website container and the database container. You will have to then, of course, create virtual hosts for each website so they do not have port conflicts.

There is a slightly more complex solution to the problem in which you use yet another Docker container to act as a proxy which directs traffic appropriately to each web site. The other solution, which is what you're trying to do now, is run multiple websites in the same container in which you have to establish [server blocks](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04) (Nginx's term for virtual hosts) for each website in the container.

In any case you should place your database in its own container and link to that container in the Docker run command or Docker-Compose setup.

Comment: Many thanks Jay. The image is what I had in mind after reading your comment but I wasn't sure if it'll work. Then, I found 'corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin' image, linked it with my `database` container which in turn was already linked to `nginx` and `php` containers. I was reading about the proxy solution but haven't tried it yet. The 'server blocks' solution unfortunately didn't work - request was reaching nginx container but did not go through the php container.

Comment: Glad to have helped Alan. The proxy solution works well (I have a couple of instances of it running in production where I needed to conserve hardware and maximize database usage.) but can be finicky to setup. Gimme' a shout if you even want to try it.